# R POSIX %H:%M:%S Time Average

Tags: r, datetime, time, posix, average

I have a data frame of character times that I need to average by provider, but I'm not sure how to average them using just the time without the date. For the example below:

```
provider   time
USA       9:26:46
USDA      9:26:18
USDA      9:10:17
OIL       10:00:00
USA       6:20:56
USDA      7:19:13
OIL       11:00:00
```

The correct output for OIL would be the average between 10:00 and 11:00, and would look like:

```
provider     average
OIL          10:30
```

Does anyone know how to average just time without incorporating date using POSIX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean` works as expected. You can format the date to %H:%M:%S afterwards.

```
df <- read.table(text="provider   time
USA       9:26:46
USDA      9:26:18
USDA      9:10:17
OIL       10:00:00
USA       6:20:56
USDA      7:19:13
OIL       11:00:00",head=TRUE)

df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time,format="%T",origin="1970-01-01")
format(as.POSIXct(tapply(df$time,df$provider,mean),origin="1970-01-01"),format="%H:%M:%S")

       OIL        USA       USDA 
"10:30:00" "07:53:51" "08:38:36"
```

To get the providers' name :

```
m <- format(as.POSIXct(tapply(df$time,df$provider,mean),origin="1970-01-01"),format="%H:%M:%S")
m <- as.data.frame(m)
m$provider <- row.names(m)
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I make it so that the names of the providers would be a column as well? Right now, the output is only the averages.